# Flask add DB entry using a form

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm a beginner learning FLASK. I'm making an app and for it I've created a DB model User, and an HTML/ JS form that takes input. What I want is to use the form information to create a new entry in the database but I am unsure on how to do it. I tried to do this

```
@app.route('/add_to_db')
def add_to_db():
    email = request.form['email']
    activated = 0;
    user = models.User(email= email, activated = 0)
    db.session.add(user)
    db.session.commit()
```

HTML Code:

```
<form onsubmit="return validateEmail(document.getElementById('email').value)" action="{{ url_for("add_to_db") }}" method="post">
    Please input your email adress: <input id="email">
    <input type="submit">
</form>
<script>
    function validateEmail(email) {
        var re = /^([\w-]+(?:\.[\w-]+)*)@((?:[\w-]+\.)*\w[\w-]{0,66})\.([a-z]{2,6}(?:\.[a-z]{2})?)$/i;
        return(re.test(email));
    }
</script>
```

But this gave me a 405 Method not allowed error.

Comment: Could you please post the html code too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A 405 error means "method not allowed". As you are sending form data, you are using a POST request and need to allow POST requests. By default only GET requests are allowed. Change the line `@app.route('/add_to_db')` to `@app.route('/add_to_db', methods=['POST'])`.